# An argument for 'ref' was not provided. Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 10

I have this line of code:

```
constructor(ref: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.el = ref.nativeElement;
  }
```

But I get this error:

```
src/app/shared/directives/custom-element.directive.ts:13:15
    13   constructor(ref: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for 'ref' was not provided.
```

Of course I googled on this error.

But I only found this type of error:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/an-argument-for-opts-was-not-provided/175401

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Comment: Adding `public` or `private` modifier should fix this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In front of the "ref:" argument name, you should put the access modifier "private", in order to use Angular's dependency injection functionality.

So:

```
constructor(ref: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

     this.el = ref.nativeElement;
    
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
constructor(private ref: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        
     this.el = ref.nativeElement;
    
}
```